# ActiveRecord - automatically merging model data as an aggregate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say I have two tables.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string    :type, :default => 'User'
      t.string    :user_name, :null => false
      t.boolean   :is_registered, :default => true
      # ... many more fields
    end
  end
end

class CreateContactInfo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :contact_info do |t|
      t.integer :resource_id
      t.string :resource_type
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :middle_initial
      t.string :title
    end
  end
end
```

```
class ContactInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contactable, :polymorphic => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact_info, :as => :contactable
  # composed_of :contact_info # ... It would be nice if magics happened here
end
```

I would like to have the User's contact_info automatically merged into my User object as attributes of the user object without having to say @user.contact_info.first_name; instead, I would prefer to be able to write @user.first_name.

The reason I am breaking out attributes to the contact_info table is that these are common attributes to multiple models.  That is why I am making setting up the contact_info as a polymorphic association.

Does anyone know of a good way to aggregate/merge the attributes of contact_info directly into my user model?

Comment: Thanks for editing and making it easier to read the code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it!  Thank you both amikazmi and Topher Fangio. I had to implement both the delegate and method_missing techniques to get this to work.

Here is the total madness that finally ended up working for me!  If anybody has suggestions on how to further improve this, I'd love to hear your suggestions.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible *([:user_name, :udid, :password, :password_confirmation, :contact_info] + ContactInfo.accessible_attributes.to_a.map {|a| a.to_sym})

  has_one :contact_info, :as => :contactable

  def method_missing(method_id, *args)
    if (!self.respond_to?(method_id) && self.contact_info.respond_to?(method_id))
      self.contact_info.send(method_id, *args)
    elsif (!self.class.respond_to?(method_id) && ContactInfo.respond_to?(method_id))
      ContactInfo.send(method_id, *args)
    else
      super(method_id, *args)
    end
  end

  # delegating attributes seems redundant with the method_missing above, but this secret sauce works.
  ContactInfo.accessible_attributes.to_a.each do |a|
    delegate a.to_sym, "#{a}=".to_sym, :to => :contact_info
  end

  def initialize(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    contact_attrs = ContactInfo.accessible_attributes.to_a.map{|a| a.to_sym}
    @ci = ContactInfo.new(options.reject {|k,v| !contact_attrs.include?(k) })
    super(*(args << options.reject { |k,v| contact_attrs.include?(k) }.merge(:contact_info => @ci) ) )
    self.contact_info = @ci
  end

  validates_presence_of :user_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name

  validates_associated  :contact_info

  def after_save
    # automatically save the contact info record for the user after the user has been saved.
    self.contact_info.save!
  end

end
```

---

```
class ContactInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "contact_info"

  belongs_to :contactable, :polymorphic => true

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  attr_accessible :first_name,
                  :last_name, 
                  :middle_initial, 
                  :title, 
                  :organization_name, 
                  :email, 
                  :email_2, 
                  :twitter_name, 
                  :website_url, 
                  :address_1, 
                  :address_2, 
                  :city, 
                  :state, 
                  :zip, 
                  :phone_work, 
                  :phone_mobile, 
                  :phone_other, 
                  :phone_other_type

  def full_name
    [self.first_name, self.last_name].compact.join(' ')
  end

end
```

Answer (score 8):

Use delegate:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact_info, :as => :contactable

  delegate :name, :name=, :email, :email=, :to => :contact_info
end
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, but I'm getting an error for example.
I implemented delegating :email to :contact_info, but it still does not work.

>> u = User.create(:email => "asdf@asdf.com")
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: email

Comment: this was only read delegation, if you want to write also, you need to add setter method "delegate :name, :email, :name=, :email="

Comment: Thank you.  That got me rolling again. This helped solve my problem.  I posted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a ***good*** way to do it, but I did something similar by overriding the [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005925) method and then calling my aggregated object. So, it would look something like:

```
class User
  def method_missing(method_id)
    self.contact_info.send(method_id)
  end
end
```

**Edit 1:** Better implementation (I think this will work):

```
class User
  alias_method :orig_method_missing, :method_missing

  def method_missing(method_id)
    if (self.contact_info.respond_to?(method_id))
      self.contact_info.send(method_id)
    else
      orig_method_missing(method_id)
    end
  end
end
```

The above has the advantage that all other unknown method calls will get passed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Your recommendation got me on the right track.